# WSL 2.0, Docker permission error with mounted volume, "Error: EACCES: permission denied"

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've got Docker Desktop installed and set up to work with my WSL 2.0 environment and have been trying to do code development within a folder in my WSL environment using a Docker image by mounting said folder and then running Docker. While I can do a command like "`docker run -v ~/projects/my_projects:/sources my_image`" and it'll mount the folder, I can't seem to actually run anything or modify anything. If I try to set my Python interpreter, edit and save any file, etc., I'm met with a "Failed to save..., NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCESS: permission denied, open ..." error. Would anyone have any ideas on how I might fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having this error also, did you managed to solve it?